# I need 2 submit buttons on my form but here's what's happening

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I need 2 submit buttons on my form. `Submit_1` is for adding a new record entry to local list. Then `Submit_2` is for sending the list to the database.

Here's what happened when I just had 1 submit on the page. I had a regular button for the `Add` to add new record to list. After adding a new record I would clear the model which would clear the entry fields.

However, when I clicked submit to save the list to the database, the validation would kick in and not let me save to the database.

The following is what I came up with so far:

```
@page "/practice"
@inject ILogger<Starship> Logger

<EditForm Model="@Model" OnSubmit="@Submit">
    <InputText @bind-Value="Model!.Id" />
    <button @onclick='()=>submitId="1"' type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button @onclick='()=>submitId="2"' type="submit">Submit 2</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    string submitId = "";
    public Starship? Model { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized() => Model ??= new();

    private void Submit()
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("Model.Id = {Id}", Model?.Id);
        Logger.LogWarning("Which submit was pressed? {0}", submitId);
    }

    public class Starship
    {
        public string? Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the form supposed to check validation of one entry ? So the submit button should be used to add an entry and the regular button to save to DB.